# give variable number type value from button JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, button

I am total beginner in JavaScript and I am stuck in one task. I need create something like calculator who do some mathematics. Sounds easy but I stuck and google with youtube don't give me answer this time.

There must be buttons where user can choose which variant he want. Than there is field where user can write own amount and in final its all count together.

Example user choose buttonOne with value = 1 write in userInput field 1 and in back-end JavaScript give extra 1.
Function is = buttonValue+ userInput + 1. So in result must be 3.

I stuck there that I can't give number value from button my variable. I got NaN in result or nothing works. NaN because JavaScript don't understand that button value is number. All other things works in my formula.

Html

```
<div class = "testCalculator">
        <h4>I want count button value + user <br> input and + 1 from javascript back -end</h4>
        <div class = "main-wrapper">
            <form>
                <div>  
                    <input type="radio" name="type" value=1 id= 1 onclick="func2();"/>button value 1<br/>
                    <input type="radio" name="type" value=2 id=2  onclick="func2();"/>button value 2 <br/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for = "userInput">User input:</label>
                    <input type = "text" id = "userInput" placeholder="0.00">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label for = "result">Final result </label>
                    <input type = "text" id = "result" placeholder="0.00" disabled = true>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <button type = "button" class = "main-btn" id = "calc-btn">Calculate</button>
        <button type = "button" class = "main-btn" id = "reset-btn">Reset</button>
    </div>
```

My

And my JavaScript code:
[JavasSript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYDQz.png)

I try add like code sample, but there was some problem and It looks like normal text so better I create picture.

Comment: Code blocks without [a language specified](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/150605) will use the question's tags to determined what syntax highlighting to perform.  This question is not tagged with any languages (i.e. Javascript) so it uses the default highlighting, which is none at all.  (The lack of a language tag also means the users best able to help you likely won't see this question.)  Still, it's almost never better to [post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/150605), in this case because another user can't edit it to fix formatting issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value from your input button by doing:

```
document.getElementById('1').value;
```

However this will return a string, so you will need to wrap the result in a `Number(  )`.

There are many different ways to get the value ie. saving the element reference to a variable separately), but the core idea is adding a `.value`.

Here is a working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31rvca0t/3/)

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what I need :)